# Are there any programs or IDEs that calculate Big-O notation on functions? Is this something that is possible to program into an IDE?

Tags: functions, big-o, algorithm-analysis

Is there anything that can calculate the Big-O notation of a function?
While learning about Big-O, it is implied that it is pretty trivial to do in your head once you know the basic rules, however if that were true, I would expect this functionality to be embedded in various IDEs. I have not seen any tool like this.

Is this something that can be easily interpreted via software, or does this require context that is only available to the developer?

Comment: You could probably estimate it by measuring the time it takes for the first few iterations of `n` to execute, assuming that the algorithm is not `O(ludicrous)`.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the interpretation of the given answers so far, so I'd like to ask you to differentiate: are you asking for a tool that analyzes a compiled program, or a tool that analyzes the source code itself (or is either acceptable)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That would require an assumption that processing performance does not vary during the test, because otherwise measuring the time is reasonably imprecise.

Comment: @Flater: there is no difference. A compiler is simply a program that translates a program from one language to another language. In other words, the compiled program is still the exact same program as the source code, only in a different language. The Halting Problem is a *general* proof of Undecidability, it does not depend on the language. You cannot escape the Halting Problem by translating to a different language.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Taken from the comments on a comment [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480775/programmatically-obtaining-big-o-efficiency-of-code) on on of the answers here: _"The halting problem doesn't say we can never do it. It says that there are programs for which it cannot be done."_ What you're arguing is the equivalent of saying that if you can't divide by zero, you therefore cannot divide by any number. Even if OP's suggested tool would only be able to handle _some_ but not all cases, that still means it's not impossible as your answer is claiming.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Additionally, since a human can look at source code and find its BigO notation, and we can teach other humans to do so as well, I have not seen any reasonable proof to exclude the possibility of a machine learning algorithm learning to do the same. If you cannot exclude that possibility, you therefore cannot conclude it is impossible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: observing the program at runtime is a neat trick to get around the Halting Problem (which after all is about deciding statically, i.e. without running the program whether it halts), but unfortunately, for your trick to work, you need to choose an appropriate value for `n`, and it can be shown that this is *also* equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @Flater: the OP is asking "Is there anything that can calculate the Big-O notation of **a function**?" (**bold** emphasis mine). Not one specific function, not a specific set of functions, but "**a**" function in general. This is not possible. While it may indeed be possible to do this for some functions, maybe even infinitely many functions, there are also infinitely many functions for which it is *not* possible. Furthermore, it can be proven that *knowing* whether it is possible for a function is *also* equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: In other words, it is *indeed* possible to write a tool which will give the right answer for infinitely many functions, but it is impossible to write a tool that will *not* give the wrong answer for infinitely many functions, *and* it is impossible to write a tool that will tell you whether it is giving you the right or the wrong answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Are you able to divide a number by another number? According to your posted answer, you should be answering "no, this is impossible", which is a clearly nonsensical answer. You **can** divide a number by another number, but there are some exceptions where it cannot be done (dividing by zero). This is not inherently an all or nothing question - if a reasonable line can be drawn where _sometimes_ it can't be done, that is not the same as stating it is impossible.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: _"there are also infinitely many functions for which it is not possible"_ And just to extend the analogy, there are infinitely many numbers which cannot be divided by zero either. I agree completely with your assertion that it can never be guaranteed, but I wholeheartedly disagree with labeling this as "outright impossible" instead of "partially (im)possible"

Comment: I think this is an excelent question and while a general solution is impossible as pointed out in the answers an interesting subset should not be to horribly complicated. (Especially if you only output the bounds of the big-o function, ie less than or equal to quadratic complexity. If there is any tool that can do this I would be interested in looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, each algorithm for which you know a theoretical complexity has its size-to-time plot, which means that for a small data samples you can get a higher execution time.

Most of current IDEs support **performance unit tests**. 
You could generate data samples with different random sizes and pass it to you unit test. 
An IDE will gather the statistics for you. 
Then you could look at a size-to-time plot and check if your assumptions about an algorithm's complexity were right.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation is methodical and depends purely on the control flow in your code so it's definitely doable but not exactly easy..

It would probably be best to let the compilers do the initial heavy lifting and just do this by analyzing the control operations in the compiled bytecode. Also, studying compilers might help with this, such as learning how they perform [code reachability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code#Analysis).

Basically (as far as I know), every instruction is constant time complexity except for backwards branches.

So if you come across any backwards branch instruction you'd need to store contextual data, especially about that loop's exit condition, and determine the Big-O of that loop.  Then multiply its complexity by the complexity of instructions contained within it, which could be other method calls or backward branches that you'd need to recursively analyze.

As for special context not known to the compiler: Big-O wouldn't care since it assumes the worst case, but you could always let your analyzer report additional things about the complexity of the method, assuming you make it smart enough.

Comment: "Definitely doable" - you may want to reconsider your claim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480775/programmatically-obtaining-big-o-efficiency-of-code

Comment: @whatsisname: From the comment on the top answer in your link: _"The halting problem doesn't say we can never do it. It says that there are programs for which it cannot be done."_ OP's question does not necessitate a 100% hit rate. If _some_ functions cannot be analyzed, so be it. But you're implying that if _some_ functions can be analyzed, then we can't analyze _any_ functions, which is does not logically follow.

Comment: "Also, studying compilers might help with this, such as learning how they perform code reachability analysis." - Unfortunately, Code Reachability Analysis is … you guessed it … equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @whatsisname Sorry, I see how that statement could be misunderstood. I didn't mean that you can program something which can solve the complexity of *every* method; It was a response to OP's question that, *yes*, you can write a program for an IDE which can solve the complexity of methods (maybe not every method though..) and, *no*, you don't need special context. I am aware of the Halting Problem which is a good part of why I included a link about reachability analysis.

Comment: @JörgWMittag See above. I feel that answering: "*no*, you cannot write a program to calculate the Big-O of functions" is not an accurate answer for what OP was asking. It may be true that you can't calculate the Big-O of *all* functions but, I am in agreement with Flater that, OP's question, as it is worded, doesn't imply "all functions" as a requirement.

Comment: @Flater: you're confusing me with the answerer. "Can be done for some function" is a long way away from "definitely doable" with no caveats. What I'm implying is the answerer should write more carefully.

Comment: @whatisname I address the meaning of "definitely doable" above. I agree telling OP about the Halting Problem doesn't hurt but they'd've likely encountered it anyway when studying code reachability. I see this question as similar to someone asking "is there a way to solve equations?"  to which the answer is of course "yes, and here's a way to do it", then someone else coming in and saying "no, sometimes there are no solutions or infinite solutions" when really "no solution" or "infinite solutions" would be acceptable answers.

Answer (score -1):

Very short answer: this is impossible, since it can be used to solve the Halting Problem.

Intuitive answer #1: "What is the algorithmic complexity of this code" is clearly a more complicated question than "Does this code stop", which we know is undecidable. If such a simple question is undecidable, then a more complicated question probably is, too.

Intuitive answer #2: If it were possible to write such a tool, then I could simply check whether the return value is smaller than infinity and solve the Halting Problem this way. Since we know the Halting Problem is undecidable, such a tool cannot possibly exist.

Correct answer: (The correct answer would be a proof of the undecidability, which I will not give here. There is a sketch of a proof in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753733/2988) to a very similar question on our sister site Stack Overflow.)

Comment: You're succumbing to a logical fallacy. "Not always" does not equate to "never". [The Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem): _"Turing proved no algorithm exists that **always** correctly decides whether, for a given arbitrary program and input, the program halts when run with that input."_ It does not state that you can _never_ do it, it states that you _can't always_ do it. A more explicit quote: _"While deciding whether these programs halt is simple, more complex programs prove problematic."_ **Some** (sufficiently simple) programs can be defined as halting or not.

Comment: @Flater You could write something that categorises things into `Some O() | Doesn't Halt | Don't Know`, but most of the interesting programs live in `Don't Know`

Comment: @Caleth: Indeed. People often both underestimate and overestimate the importance and reach of the HP. Microsoft Research's Terminator (which now ships as part of the Windows Driver Development Kit) *does* check whether code halts. BUT! This only works for a very restricted subset of programs, namely Windows device drivers written in a specific restricted subset of C++ in a specific style against a specific restricted set of APIs and *even then*, there are many cases where it can neither prove termination nor non-termination, and thus has no choice but to reject the driver.

Comment: @Caleth: Even if it can only answer trivial functions, it would still have a purpose as either a training tool or a safety guard against (or to point out) simple mistakes. Not every bug is intricate, not every test is testing contrived behaviors.